# T-SQL list of years and months between two dates

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with a list of individuals that have a effective date and a termination date. 
example Person 1, 20171201, 20180601
For each record, I need to output a list of years and months they were "active" between the two dates.
So the output would look like

[Data Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lNc63.png)

This is in SQL Server 2016
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Remember this is a forum to help overcome difficulties, rather than a homework-solving forum. BTW, that screenshot says "person1, person2, etc." I guess that's not correct, right? Should the "to" date be excluded? Finally, this kind of logic usually belongs to the application rather than the database. Does this *really* have to be done at SQL level?

Comment: @Andrew yes I have tried a few examples I have found but nothing gets me to the output that I want. 
You are correct in the picture is incorrect and it should be Person1 repeated for each active year/month (this has been corrected)
To answer your last question, yes this needs to be done at the SQL level as there is no application on top of it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please avoid posting pictures of data or code... especially when it is such a small amount of information to cut/paste such as in your question.

Comment: We can't answer this question.   You need to show us the full data model (as input) and the expected output.  You have not shown the inputs.  With any possible input there is any possible code that would create the output you describe.  Please post the full DDL of the source table.  Also, post any code you expected to work, but it did not do what you expected.

Comment: I suggest a Date Table or a Tally.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on info you've provided, I did a little guessing. Perhaps a recursive CTE will help:

```
DECLARE @tab TABLE (Person INT, EffectiveDate DATE, TerminationDate DATE)
INSERT @tab VALUES
(1, '2017-12-01', '2018-05-31'),
(2, '2017-10-01', '2018-01-01'),
(3, '2018-02-01', '2018-12-01')

;WITH t AS (
    SELECT Person, EffectiveDate AS Dt
    FROM @tab
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Person, DATEADD(mm,1,Dt)
    FROM t
    WHERE t.Dt < (SELECT DATEADD(mm,-1,TerminationDate) FROM @tab tt WHERE tt.Person = t.Person)
    )

SELECT *
FROM t
ORDER BY Dt
```

Then take the `DATEPART()`

```
SELECT t.Person
     , t.Dt
     , DATEPART(yyyy, t.Dt) ActiveYear
     , DATEPART(mm, t.Dt) ActiveMonth
FROM t
ORDER BY Dt
```

Comment: For basic counting Recursive CTEs will perform horribly. Note this article that details the issue: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/hidden-rbar-counting-with-recursive-ctes

Comment: Thank you very much for your example. I was looking at the table variable, just couldn't get the syntax correct and probably should have posted it. I took your example, compared it to mine and found my mistake. 
The issue now is I am now running into a "Maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion" error. Some of the dates have quite the distance between them. 
I will do some more research on my side.
Thank you again for your answer. I think it gets me close to what I want!

Answer (score 1):

Just because I did not see it offered.  Here is yet another approach which uses an ad-hoc calendar table

Note the base date of 2000-01-01 and 10,000 days ... expand or contract if needed

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable table (Person int,startdate date,  enddate date)
Insert Into @YourTable values 
(1,'20171201','20180601')

Select Distinct 
       A.Person
      ,ActiveYear = year(D)
      ,ActiveMonth = month(D)
From  @YourTable A
Join  (
          Select Top 10000 D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),'2000-01-01') 
                From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
      ) B on D between startdate and enddate
```

**Returns**

```
Person  ActiveYear  ActiveMonth
1       2017        12
1       2018        1
1       2018        2
1       2018        3
1       2018        4
1       2018        5
1       2018        6
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow! For better help it's good to include DDL easily consumable sample data that we can use to quickly re-create what you are doing and provide a solution. Note this sample data:

```
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE(person VARCHAR(20), date1 DATE, date2 DATE)
INSERT @yourtable (person, date1, date2) 
VALUES ('Person1','20171201', '20180601'), ('Person2','20171001', '20180101'),
       ('Person3','20180101', '20180301');

SELECT t.* FROM @yourtable AS t;
```

**Returns:**

```
person               date1      date2
-------------------- ---------- ----------
Person1              2017-12-01 2018-06-01
Person2              2017-10-01 2018-01-01
Person3              2018-01-01 2018-03-01
```

(I added a couple rows). Here's my solution:

```
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE(person VARCHAR(20), date1 DATE, date2 DATE)
INSERT @yourtable (person, date1, date2) 
VALUES ('Person1','20171201', '20180601'), ('Person2','20171001', '20180101'),
       ('Person3','20180101', '20180301');

SELECT 
  Person      = t.person,
    ActiveYear  = YEAR(st.DT),
  ActiveMonth = MONTH(st.Dt)
FROM   @yourtable AS t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(MONTH,t.date1,t.date2)) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
  FROM       (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS a(x)
  CROSS JOIN (VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS b(x)
) AS iTally(N)
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(DATEADD(MONTH, iTally.N-1, t.date1))) AS st(Dt);
```

**Which returns:**

```
Person               ActiveYear  ActiveMonth
-------------------- ----------- -----------
Person1              2017        12
Person1              2018        1
Person1              2018        2
Person1              2018        3
Person1              2018        4
Person1              2018        5
Person2              2017        10
Person2              2017        11
Person2              2017        12
Person3              2018        1
Person3              2018        2
```

Let me know if you have questions.